# Percentage based on another column, with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what I have:

```
create table Test(day int, status varchar(50), transactions int);
insert into Test(day, status, transactions) values(5, "success", 105);
insert into Test(day, status, transactions) values(5, "success", 105);
insert into Test(day, status, transactions) values(5, "failure", 40);
insert into Test(day, status, transactions) values(6, "success", 40);
insert into Test(day, status, transactions) values(6, "failure", 32);
insert into Test(day, status, transactions) values(7, "success", 552);
insert into Test(day, status, transactions) values(7, "failure", 4);

select day, status, sum(transactions) from Test
group by day, status
```

getting this one:

```
day status  sum(transactions)
5   success 210
5   failure 40
6   success 40
6   failure 32
7   success 552
7   failure 4
```

I want to have additional column, telling me per day how much is my success rate. E.g. `210/(210+40)` for day 5, 40/(32+40) for day 6 etc:

```
day status  sum(transactions)   rate
5   success 210                 0.8400
5   failure 40                  0.1600
6   success 40                  0.5556
6   failure 32                  0.4444
7   success 552                 0.9928
7   failure 4                   0.0072
```

Comment: Do you want the success rate as a separate query result?
Its unclear how you want this as additional column in your above query since it has 2 rows per day

Comment: @hsnsd - well, the one can be `105/(105+40)` for success and the other `40/(105+40` for failure rate.

Comment: The query in your question does not return the results that you say you get. The last column that count returns should be filled with 1s. Edit your question and also post your expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas - true, I have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can get the rates (success/failure) for equivalent status type.

```
select t.day, t.status, sum(transactions), sum(transactions)/total  as rate
from Test t inner join (select day, sum(transactions) as total from Test group by day) total
on t.day = total.day
group by t.day, t.status
```

Output:

```
day status  sum(transactions)   rate
5   failure    40               0.2759
5   success    105              0.7241
```